# Newbie in android programming, xml and class file not working

Tags: android

I have a problem I have created a simple list items and my item is Entertainment I have created the XML and Java file but after running into an emulator it doesn't work. I mean list items work, entertainment is here but clicking it won't make it to the next. Help

This is the main activity file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Java file:

```
package com.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Entertainment extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer ourSong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.entertainment);
        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.id.videoView1);
        ourSong.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingpoint = new Intent(
                            "com.bucky.android.Menu");
                    startActivity(openStartingpoint);

                }
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.release();
        finish();

    }

}
```

And this is the manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.firstapp.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity
        android:name="com.firstapp.Entertainment"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Where have you defined your `Menu` activity in AndroidMenifest ?

Comment: Which is your launcher activity ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Manifest, the tag "category" in your main activity intent is wrong:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.firstapp.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You have to declare LAUNCHER instead of DEFAULT. See if it works after this change.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override itemclick method of your listview for that

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    int position = arg2;

    // click event handling
    textQuestionCount.setText("Question " + String.valueOf(position + 1) + " of " + arg0.getCount());

    }
```

and also implement the interface `OnItemClickListener` in your class.